# Sensitive data not being removed

Tags: git, github

I have oauth information stored in a .js file on github, but it's not being removed when I try to purge it.

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch config" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, with git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0.

After I did all this that github commit still exists on github. Can someone please help me and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Problem solved: The file was named config.js, not config. Thanks

Edit:

```
Rewrite f8899b62eca2db6bee196e9096e50af54a11dce6 (13/27)rm 'config.js'
Rewrite 7d552dfff83f73680319339199b453fe2c68c486 (14/27)rm 'config.js'
Rewrite af45e665de54b5742c5b7a2abc42930bc3a495a7 (15/27)rm 'config.js'
Rewrite 43ed6fdd603bed538f938b4032327387b5ba678d (16/27)rm 'config.js'
error: duplicate parent 0e53d2d536c4804eb2dd085a6d0a9d9b004efa66 ignor
Rewrite e075498a66de25641d29f02f772f2a026aa2168d (17/27)rm 'config.js'
Rewrite 5312d1b1ae8e0f232daaa05aae630eb016cc417f (18/27)rm 'config.js'
Rewrite 55279be6bf144ea601525523b6262f5d20baebd2 (24/27)rm 'config.js'
Rewrite 3c4534f639742cb33ffb6f43ad1ca6d0df783b3f (25/27)rm 'config.js'
Rewrite ca4a556bdf8efb131786d0b7219098312d5edb0d (27/27)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' was rewritten
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
```

Comment: Is the commit gone from your local copy?

Comment: No it is not, but it didn't work yesterday even after I removed it from my local copy. Man why is GitHub so hard to use..  When I remove it from my "local copy" and I try to do the filter-branch I get "Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes."

Comment: If the file is still in one of your branches locally, pushing to GitHub won't accomplish much. It needs to be properly removed locally before you push. Check out [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), which is a tool that many people like for this kind of thing. GitHub [endorses it](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/#using-the-bfg).

Comment: I don't have Java, nor do I want it.

Comment: I didn't type it, you can see that in the code block. That's just the code that I copied from. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The "WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged" message is a problem... The `filter-branch` command should have rewritten it, assuming you ever committed `config` to `master`.

Comment: I did look it's here: https://github.com/IntelvsAMD/IVABot/commit/a3f7129e3e6aabc77fb0d720848b536b6994082e

Comment: No it's not. That file is called `config.js`, not `config`. If that's the file you're trying to get rid of, you need to change your `filter-branch` call to `... "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch config.js" ...`.

Comment: Now it worked, it's still in the commit history though. Nevermind: had to do git push origin --force --all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is *vital* that you nullify the compromised OAuth information and generate new credentials. I recommend doing this even before you worry about cleaning up your history.**

Unfortunately, there are bots that look for this kind of stuff:

- http://www.devfactor.net/2014/12/30/2375-amazon-mistake/
- http://wptavern.com/ryan-hellyers-aws-nightmare-leaked-access-keys-result-in-a-6000-bill-overnight

Your `filter-branch` command looks good¹. Once you get your history cleaned up locally, you'll need to force push to GitHub:

```
git push origin --force --all
```

The offending commits will remain on GitHub until `git-gc` is run on the server. You could wait for this to happen, or you could [submit a support ticket](https://github.com/contact) asking for it to be run on your repository.

¹Make sure that the full filename, including extension, matches the `... "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch config" ...` part.

Comment: Isn't that what I did here? "git push origin --force --all"
Also, how long does git-gc take? I did this yesterday and nothing happened today.

Comment: GitHub runs `gc` as often as it needs to. As far as I know, there is no official schedule. Either wait, or submit a ticket. But that is of secondary importance to invalidating the compromised credentials.

Comment: What do you mean by "once I get my history cleaned up locally"?

Comment: @ECMAScript, I mean once your local copy's history no longer contains the file. That's the whole point of the `filter-branch` command you're trying to run.

Comment: So do I run the filter-branch command when the file isn't on my local computer? Do I need to push after I do filter branch?

Comment: @ECMAScript, it doesn't particularly matter whether the file is there or not. Yes, you need to push (with `--force`) after you run `filter-branch`.

Comment: You're the best, thanks. I realize that I need to learn more about git so I'll watch a lynda.com course on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the backup refs and the reflog entries before doing a `git gc`?

Check with

```
git rev-list --objects --all | grep config
```

if the file is deleted.

I also wrote a blog about deleting files from a git repository. You will find more information there [Remove directories and files permanently from git](http://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2014/07/17/remove-directories-and-files-permanently-from-git/).

I also published a gui tool on github that helps to delete files. More about this tool here: [GitDirStat – a git maintenance gui](http://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2014/12/28/gitdirstat-a-git-maintenance-gui/). The actual [release](https://github.com/link-intersystems/GitDirStat/releases) can be downloaded. It's pure java.

Comment: The OP has already said "I don't have Java, nor do I want it".

Comment: @Chris Ok, so the OP might only be interressted in the first blog. It's about deleting files only via command line and it describes the basics behind it.